# nth-child(even) and nth-child(odd)

Tags: html, css

I have a little problem and maybe there is someone who can help me.

I have a list of articles and on some pages the article size is even and on some there are odd, I want to remove the bottom border from the last one / last two items

I have tried something like this on my list:

```
.wrapper_grid_view{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: grid;
    grid-auto-flow: row;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-right: -2%;
    max-width: 100%;
}

.wrapper_grid_view > div{
    text-align: center;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.wrapper_grid_view > div:last-child:nth-child(odd){
    text-align: center;
    border-bottom: none;
}

.wrapper_grid_view > div:last-child:nth-child(even):nth-last-of-type(-n+2){
    text-align: center;
    border-bottom: none;
}
```

the odd one is working fine and the border-bottoms is removed correctly, however when the article list is even, it only removes 1 border-bottom instead of the last  2

[image][image]

my template is a bit bigger:

thats the 1.st part :

```
<div [{if $view_type == 'grid_view' && $view_type_style == 'grid_view'}] class="wrapper_grid_view" [{elseif $view_type == 'list_view' && $view_type_style == 'list_view'}] class="row stproducts" [{/if}]>
            [{if $oView->stHasSpecialContent('content_productlist_top')}]
                [{$oView->stGetSpecialContent('content_productlist_top')}]
            [{/if}]
            [{php}]$this->assign('allRatings', oxRegistry::get('subtelUtils')->getProductRatingsForArticleList($this->get_template_vars('products')));[{/php}]
            [{foreach from=$products item=_product name=productlist}]
                [{php}]oxRegistry::get('subtelUtils')->cacheAddSKUDependency( $this->get_template_vars('_product')->getId() );[{/php}]
                [{include file="widget/product/listitem_flex.tpl" product=$_product allRatings=$allRatings testid=$listId|cat:"_"|cat:$smarty.foreach.productlist.iteration blDisableToCart=$blDisableToCart nProductPosition=$nProductPosition}]
                [{assign var="nProductPosition" value=$nProductPosition+1}]
            [{/foreach}]
        </div>
```

This is the second:

```
 <div itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer" [{if $view == 'grid_view'}]id="price_grid_view"[{/if}] class="product-price">
    [{*oxmultilang ident="DX_BRUTTO"*}]
    [{if $oxCat and $oxCat->getId() == 'blackfriday2015' and $subDiscountId}]
    <strong class="simple">[{$discPrice->getPrice()|number_format:2:",":"."}] [{$currency->sign}]</strong>
    <strong class="simple" style="font-size: 16px; text-decoration: line-through;">
        [{if $stPriceStyle eq 'cp'}]
        <span itemprop="priceCurrency" content="[{$currency->name}]"> [{$currency->sign}] </span>
        <span itemprop="price" content="[{$unformattedPrice->getPrice()}]"> [{$formattedPrice}] </span>
        [{else}]
        <span itemprop="price" content="[{$unformattedPrice->getPrice()}]"> [{$formattedPrice}] </span>
        <span itemprop="priceCurrency" content="[{$currency->name}]"> [{$currency->sign}] </span>
        [{/if}]
    </strong>
    [{else}]
    <strong class="simple">
        [{* TODO: the new/problematic way: $unformattedPrice ist ein objekt - es sollte dann $unformattedPrice->getPrice() sein damit er die sugabe macht*}]
        [{if $stPriceStyle eq 'cp'}]
        <span itemprop="priceCurrency" content="[{$currency->name}]">[{$currency->sign}]</span>
        <span [{*if $subDiscountId && $unformattedPrice->getPrice() != $product->getOldPrice()}] style="color: red" [{/if*}] itemprop="price" content="[{$unformattedPrice->getPrice()}]">
            [{if $subDiscountId && $unformattedPrice->getPrice() != $product->getOldPrice()}]
                <div style="color:#888; text-decoration:line-through;font-weight: 700;font-size: 22px;margin-top: -5px;margin-bottom: -5px; display: inline">
                    [{$product->getOldPrice()|number_format:2:",":"."}] <span>[{$currency->sign}]</span>
                </div>
                <div style="color:#888; font-weight: 700;font-size: 22px;margin-top: -5px;margin-bottom: 2px; display: inline"> | </div>
            [{/if}]
            [{if $product->isRangePrice()}]
                [{oxmultilang ident="PRICE_FROM"}]
            [{/if}]
            [{$formattedPrice}]
        </span>
        [{else}]
        <span  [{*if $subDiscountId && $unformattedPrice->getPrice() != $product->getOldPrice()}] style="color: red" [{/if*}] itemprop="price" content="[{$unformattedPrice->getPrice()}]">
                                        [{if $product->isRangePrice()}]
                                            [{oxmultilang ident="PRICE_FROM"}]
                                        [{/if}]
                                        [{$formattedPrice}]
                                    </span>
        <span  [{*if $subDiscountId && $unformattedPrice->getPrice() != $product->getOldPrice()}] style="color: red" [{/if*}] itemprop="priceCurrency" content="[{$currency->name}]">[{$currency->sign}]</span>
        [{*******Discount Price*******}]
        [{*[{if $subDiscountId && $unformattedPrice->getPrice() != $product->getOldPrice()}]
            <div style="color:#888; font-weight: 700;font-size: 22px;margin-top: -5px;margin-bottom: 2px; display: inline"> | </div>
            <div style="color:#888; text-decoration:line-through;font-weight: 700;font-size: 22px;margin-top: -5px;margin-bottom: -5px; display: inline">
                $product->getOldPrice()|number_format:2:",":"."}] <span>[{$currency->sign}]</span>
            </div>
            [{/if}]*}]
        [{/if}]
    </strong>
        [{/if}]
            [{*
            [{if $shopDomain == 'ch'}]
                [{*do not show either*}]
            [{*
            [{elseif $vatInfo.charge==1}]
                <span style="padding-bottom:2px;">[{oxmultilang ident="ST_VAT_INFO"}]</span>
            [{else}]
                <span style="padding-bottom:2px;">[{oxmultilang ident="ST_VAT_EXC_INFO"}]</span>
            [{/if}]
            *}]
            </div>
            [{*if $shopDomain == 'ch'}]
            [{elseif $vatInfo.charge==1}]
                <div style="font-size:10px;">[{oxmultilang ident="ST_VAT_INFO"}] [{oxifcontent ident="st_zahlung_versand" object="oCont"}]<a href="[{$oCont->getLink()}]" rel="nofollow">[{oxmultilang ident="ST_SHIP_INFO"}]</a>[{/oxifcontent}]</div>
            [{else}]
                <div style="font-size:10px;">[{oxmultilang ident="ST_VAT_EXC_INFO"}] [{oxifcontent ident="st_zahlung_versand" object="oCont"}]<a href="[{$oCont->getLink()}]" rel="nofollow">[{oxmultilang ident="ST_SHIP_INFO"}]</a>[{/oxifcontent}]</div>
            [{/if*}]
            [{/oxhasrights}]
            [{/if}]
            [{if $view != 'grid_view'}]
                <div class="product-basket">
                <div class="stockbox">
            [{else}]
                <div class="delivery_status_grid_view">
            [{/if}]
                [{if $currentStockAmt <= 0}]
                    [{if !$blSubtelOutOfOrder}]
                        <span class="stockFlag">
                            [{if $subDiscountId}]
                                [{assign var="delDate" value=$product->getDeliveryDate()}]
                                [{assign_adv var="subParams" value="array('0' => '$delDate', '1' => '$subDiscPercent')"}]
                                [{if $subDiscountId != 'fcced35a138f30d11c52ba6299d67a35'}]
                                    [{oxmultilang ident="ST_DISCOUNT_TITLE_`$subDiscountId`" args=$subParams}]
                                [{/if}]
                            [{/if}]
                        </span>
                        [{*<p>
                            [{if $subDiscountId }]
                                <b>[{oxmultilang ident="ST_DISCOUNT_SHORT_TITLE_`$subDiscountId`" args=$subDiscPercent}] </b><br>
                            [{/if}]
                        </p>*}]
                    [{else}]
                        <span class="stockFlag">
                            <b>[{oxmultilang ident="SUBTEL_STOCK_MANAGEMENT_NOT_AVAILABLE"}]</b>
                        </span>
                    [{/if}]
                [{else}]
                    <span class="stockFlag">
                        [{oxmultilang ident="ST_ON_STOCK_BLACK" args=$currentStockAmt}]
                    </span>
                    [{*<p>
                        [{if $subDiscountId }]
                            <b>[{oxmultilang ident="ST_DISCOUNT_SHORT_TITLE_`$subDiscountId`" args=$subDiscPercent}] </b><br>
                        [{/if}]
                    </p>*}]
                [{/if}]
                [{if $view != 'grid_view'}]
                    </div>
                </div>
                [{else}]
                </div>
                [{/if}]
            </div>
            <div [{if $view != 'grid_view'}] class="col-md-6 list-basket" [{else}] class="basket_grid_view" [{/if}]>
                [{oxhasrights ident="TOBASKET"}]
                    [{if !$blSubtelOutOfOrder}]
                        <span [{if $view != 'grid_view'}] class="list-bamt" [{else}] class="quantity_grid"  [{/if}]>
                            <span class="stdropdown">
                                <span><i class="simg simg-dropmd"></i></span>
                                <select>
                                    [{assign var="aOptions" value=','|explode:"1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9"}]
                                    [{*SUBTEL: If the OXSTOCKFLAG == 3 the article is EoL -> order qty must not exceed available stock*}]
                                    [{foreach from=$aOptions item=sOpt name=OptionCounter}]
                                        [{if $sOpt <= $currentStockAmt}]
                                            [{* Artikel auf Lager, dann max. die Anzahl die auf Lager ist *}]
                                            <option value="[{$smarty.foreach.OptionCounter.iteration}]" [{if $sOpt eq 1}]selected[{/if}]>[{$sOpt}]</option>
                                        [{elseif $product->oxarticles__oxstockflag->value eq 1 and $currentStockAmt <= 0}]
                                            [{* Artikel unbegrenzt vorbestellbar *}]
                                            <option value="[{$smarty.foreach.OptionCounter.iteration}]" [{if $sOpt eq 1}]selected[{/if}]>[{$sOpt}]</option>
                                        [{/if}]
                                    [{/foreach}]
                                </select>
                            </span>
                        </span>
                    [{/if}]
                    [{block name="subtel_listitem_flex_button_add_to_cart"}]
                        <span>
                            [{if !$blSubtelOutOfOrder}]
                                <button data-product-id="[{$product->oxarticles__oxid->value}]" onclick="stAddToCart(this)" selfurl="[{$oViewConf->getSslSelfLink()|oxaddparams:"cl=basket&amp;fnc=tobasket&amp;aid=`$product->oxarticles__oxid->value`"}]" class="btn btn-info cart st_add_to_cart" title="[{$cartBtnTitle}]"><i class="simg simg-wicartsm"></i>[{$cartBtnTitle}]</button>
                                [{*$oViewConf->getSslSelfLink()|oxaddparams:"cl=basket&amp;fnc=tobasket&amp;aid=`$product->oxarticles__oxid->value`"*}]
                                [{*$oView->getLink()|oxaddparams:"fnc=tobasket&amp;aid=`$product->oxarticles__oxid->value`"*}]
                            [{else}]
                                <button style="cursor: not-allowed; background: grey; border-color: darkgrey;" type="button" class="btn btn-info cart st_add_to_cart" title="[{$cartBtnTitle}]"><i class="simg simg-wicartsm"></i>[{$cartBtnTitle}]</button>
                            [{/if}]
                        </span>
                    [{/block}]
                [{/oxhasrights}]
    [{if $view != 'grid_view'}]
        </div>
    </div>
    [{/if}]
    [{else}]
        <div class="productinfo col-12" style="margin-top: -15px;">
            <img src="/out/subtel2/img/easter2017/new_icon.jpg">
        </div>
    [{/if}]
    [{if $view != 'grid_view'}]</div>[{/if}]
    </div>
    [{/block}]
</div>
```

Comment: Is the first image is odd and 2nd one is even? 2nd Image seems fine

Comment: Please show your html - most likely though you can't have 2 last children

Comment: yes the first image is odd this is fine how it is, the second one i want to remove the border-bottom from the left article (battery for Toschiba)

Comment: @Pete ill add my html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your last child selectors will only ever remove the last child, so the following should work for you:

```css
.container {
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.container div {
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
  width: 45%;
}

.container div:last-child,                         /* always have no border on last child */
.container div:nth-child(odd):nth-last-child(2) {  /* have no border 2nd to last child if it is odd */
  border-bottom-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>border</div>
  <div>border</div>
  <div>no border</div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div>border</div>
  <div>border</div>
  <div>no border</div>
  <div>no border</div>
</div>
```